How to texture a cartoony look?
I've been modeling for some time but I wanna know how to texture like this image because I don't understand how to do it or how to get started on doing it.


That looks like it might just be abuse of subsurface scattering, or maybe the bevel node.

That looks is mostly known as "Stylized" you can search for tutorials on youtube, no matter the software, it's basically the same
